# Critical point of $x - 5x^{\frac{1}{5}}$

Tags: derivatives

$f(x) = x - 5x^{\frac{1}{5}}$

Find the critical point

This is what I did.

\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x - 5x^{\frac{1}{5}}\\
f'(x) & = 1 - x^{-\frac{4}{5}}\\
f'(x) & = \frac{x^{\frac{4}{5}} - 1}{x^{\frac{4}{5}}}
\end{align*}

The critical points that I found are $0$ and $1$. Am I missing anything else?

I made the top portion of the fraction equals to zero as such
\begin{align*}
x^{\frac{4}{5}} - 1 & = 0\\
x & = 1
\end{align*}

Then the bottom portion of the fraction equals to zero
\begin{align*}
x^{\frac{4}{5}} & = 0\\
x & = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: What is your definition of *critical point* ?

Answer (score 2):

Your work is fine but the conclusion isn't: $0$ is not a critical point because the derivative is not even defined there.

The [usual definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) of *critical point* is a point where the derivative is zero. In particular, the derivative has to be defined at that point.

Under a [more general definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticalPoint.html) of *critical point* as a point where the derivative is either not defined or is zero, then both $1$ and $0$ would be critical points.

Comment: ah, one of the standard calculus texts: Stewart's Calculus thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If your function is $x-5x^{1/5}$ then it's not defined at $0$. So $0$ is not a critical point. But if it is $x-5\sqrt[5]{x}$ then yes, the critical points are $0$ and $1$, but also $-1$.

Comment: Oh, my gosh. Now I see it! I missed that real hard. Thanks

Comment: "If your function is $x-5x^{1/5}$ then"... it seems perfectly defined at $0$.

Comment: @Did: Usually, the function $x^\alpha$ is defined only for $x>0$.

Comment: No, not if $\alpha\gt0$.

Comment: Well, as a rational $1/5=(-2)/(-5)$. Anyhow, that might be different views. In that case, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the derivative equal to zero gives the equation $1-x^{-4/5}=0$. Solving this for $x$ gives the answer $x=1$.